# Update(change) user-defined metadata of the AWS S3 object with iOS SDK

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

Can anybody help with that?

I tried to use AWSS3ReplicateObjectRequest setting bucket, key and replicateSource properties to point the same existing S3 file, setting metadataDirective to AWSS3MetadataDirectiveReplace and assigning new user-defined metadata. In that case I have error:

```
Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSGeneralErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation
couldn’t be completed. (com.amazonaws.AWSGeneralErrorDomain error 3.)"
UserInfo=0x7ae60ef0 {Message=The request signature we calculated does not
match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method. ...
```

Have I missed something here?
(AWS iOS SDK v2.2.4)

**Update:**

```
AWSS3 *s3 = [AWSS3 S3ForKey:s3Key];
AWSS3ReplicateObjectRequest *request = [[AWSS3ReplicateObjectRequest alloc] init];
request.bucket = MYAmazonS3BucketName;
request.key = self.s3ObjectKey;
request.replicateSource = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                           MYAmazonS3BucketName,
                           self.s3ObjectKey];
request.contentType = @"application/octet-stream";
NSDictionary *metadata = @{@"type" : @"my_type",
                           @"note" : @"the_note"};
request.metadata = metadata;
request.metadataDirective = AWSS3MetadataDirectiveReplace;

[[s3 replicateObject:request] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
    if (task.error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Result: %@", task.result);
    }

    return nil;
}];
```

The authentication is performed with Cognito. I can upload/download/delete the object, can get the metadata separately.

Comment: You should post code snippets and details steps to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code snippet.

Comment: I can run the code snippet without any issues. You may wanna make sure your credentials provider is set up correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems that you are correct, after reinstallation of the app on the simulator the problem gone (. I'll update the answer when have the exact reason and solution.